# Adobe AIR for iPhone app: can't play audio properly

Tags: audio, adobe, air

I just developed an App by using adobe air. It contains some animations with background music in mp3 format. The problem is that the music is very jerky when the animation is playing...
FYI, this is the way how I play audio in flash:`new Sound(new URLRequest("m3.mp3")).play()`
Have I done anything wrong?

BTW, the funny thing is that if you hit the HOME button, and then come back to the app again, everything plays beautifully...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the code, it seems like the sound is not fully loaded.  The file plays as far as it can, then waits for more data to show up, then continues . . . very jerky.  You may have to wait for the sound to load completely before playing it:

```
var s = new air.Sound(); 
s.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded); 
var req = new air.URLRequest("bigSound.mp3"); 
s.load(req); 

function onSoundLoaded(event) 
{ 
    var localSound = event.target; 
    localSound.play(); 
}
```

This code is from [Adobe's Sound docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cfb.html).